# Convert Time Stamp from rosbag(Topic) to Understandable Format Y/M/D H:M:S

Tags: ros-melodic, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi  someone would you know what the following TimeStamp means? and how to convert it to seconds or other understable format such year/month/day Hour:Minutes:Seconds?

I have a car-robot that has driven 80 meters in about 1 min of simulation. However when I recorded the rosbag I had the:
**First Timestamp =1,63277521885359E+018**
and the
**Last TimeStamp from this topic (odom) = 1,63277529735619E+018**

I do not know to convert this data to an understandable format such as **Y/M/D H:M:S**
Some **tool makes the trick?** Or some Python Library such as DateTime (how to specific use, suitable class to apply?)

I have done some research herehttps://discourse.ros.org/t/timestamps-and-rosbags-discussing-an-alternative-to-clock-and-use-sim-time/3238/9 But  these steps seem too complex http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook

In addition, I got another column in my rosbag called field.header.sec
that intuitively should return the seconds. But assessing this data again. The first/end data are:

**T0 = 7348
TF = 8036**

Subtracting these values I have **688 seconds = 11 minutes**. And this is **Not realistic** because I have killed the simulation and the rosbag after 2 minutes( max) and the car in the simulation achieved the goal after 1 min, not 11 minutes....
I wonder how to understand and convert the TimeStamp extracted from rosbags.
If someone could help me, I would be very grateful

Beginning of csv file (localizer or odom topic)

https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/business7/uploads/ros/original/2X/f/f3cb0d690ea58fdb73a36d2d14afdd64462c9a58.png

End of csv file

https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/business7/uploads/ros/original/2X/7/7773cabae44ccebc654301fcf9877eada01dde44.png

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388683/convert-time-stamp-from-rosbag(topic)-to-understandable-format-y/m/d-h:m:s/) by [Vini71](https://answers.ros.org/users/37882/vini71/) on ROS Answers with karma: 266 on 2021-10-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-10-14**:
Did you cross-post this to ROS Discourse [here](https://discourse.ros.org/t/timestamps-and-rosbags-discussing-an-alternative-to-clock-and-use-sim-time/3238/9)?

**Comment by [Vini71](https://answers.ros.org/users/37882/vini71/) on 2021-10-14**:
yes sorry I am trying to get as much ideas as possible to help on this issue.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-10-14**:
That's not how it works, and is actually pretty annoying. At best it leads to duplicated answers. In most cases it leads to wasted effort.

And it's not such a special problem. The Q&As I've linked in my answer already discuss this, and they're years old.

**Comment by [Vini71](https://answers.ros.org/users/37882/vini71/) on 2021-10-14**:
Ok....I respect your point of view...because actually there are different channels, different experts that will visualize...so..., I think different..but ok.

Could you take a look at my own answer below, please? I am trying to figure out what is wrong with the code.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-10-14**:
It's not just my point of view: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossposting

**Comment by [Vini71](https://answers.ros.org/users/37882/vini71/) on 2021-10-14**:
Hummm ok I got the idea @gvdhoorn, I have tooken a quick read...so much rules to be aware...not easy. But thanks to share these rules to me. I will try to follow all of them. Additionally let me ask you, I have edited the question on ROS Discourse, and instead put the whole question as here I have just put this link of ROS Answers for other ROS users visualize. Would this be the right manner or not? I mean if I wish that some question be visualized by different communities...which is the right way?? And thanks again for your answer!! It saved my time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I have a car-robot that has driven 80 meters in about 1 min of simulation. However when I recorded the rosbag I had the: First Timestamp =1,63277521885359E+018 and the Last TimeStamp from this topic (odom) = 1,63277529735619E+018
>
> I do not know to convert this data to an understandable format such as Y/M/D H:M:S Some tool makes the trick?

Afaik, this is just a Unix Epoch stamp. See #q273953 or #q296045 for instance.

If you run `rosbag info /path/to/your.bag`, it should show you something like this (from [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#rosbag_info)):

```
start:       Jun 17 2010 14:24:58.83 (1276809898.83)
end:         Jun 17 2010 14:25:00.01 (1276809900.01)
```

note the number in brackets: that's the Unix Epoch stamp. The 'human readable' version is printed before it.

> In addition, I got another column in my rosbag called field.header.sec that intuitively should return the seconds.

`field.header.seq` is not a timestamp. Is the *sequence ID* field. That's just a message counter.

Refer to [std_msgs/Header](http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Header.html):

> ```
> # sequence ID: consecutively increasing ID
> ```

```
uint32 seq
```

---

Edit:

> but for the data I have, that is

> unix_epoch_timestamp_t0 Out[29]: 1632775218853592670

> and unix_epoch_timestamp_tf Out[30]: 1632775297356186066

`1632775218853592670` is not a valid Unix Epoch stamp. Or at least, not for the functions you are using, as they will expect a resolution of *seconds*. Note the warning `epochconverter.com` gives you:

> Assuming that this timestamp is in nanoseconds

You're likely concatenating the seconds and the nanoseconds from the `std_msgs/Header` colums in your `.csv` as strings, and then trying to interpret that as a single number. That doesn't work.

You can probably pass `time.localtime(..)` a `float`, in the form of `seconds.nanoseconds`:

```
>>> time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", time.localtime(1632775297.356186066))
'Mon, 27 Sep 2021 22:41:37 +0000'
```

Note that your format string doesn't allow for showing the nanosecond precision of the stamp, and Python renders this in my local timezone (UTC+2). I'm also not sure hard-coding a `+0000` for the time-zone is a good idea.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0